# Decoding URL in PHP

Tags: php, html, dom, decode, encode

I am passing url variables, and this URL variables has been encoded. My goal was to decode the URL that has been passed and use this URL to get its DOM. The code below is what I am using but failed to accomplish my goal. It just shows a blank page. But if I decode the url first manually and try it, it works.

NOTE, the URL has an extention of MP4 but it is in html format. So don't let it confuse you.

```
$url_link = urldecode('http%3A%2F%2Fplaybb.me%2Fembed.php%3Fw%3D600%26%23038%3Bh%3D438%26%23038%3Bvid%3Dat%2Fnw%2Fzettai_shougeki_platonic_heart_-_01.mp4');
$html = file_get_html($url_link);    
$raw_html = $html->find('html', 0)->innertext;    
echo $raw_html;
```

Comment: Does it even matter?

Comment: Madara knows everything, he doesn't have a question himself, he is the answer

Comment: Your code works fine, on a URL with a standard HTML Dom structure.  I think your problem is the external page - not your code.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that I am trying to use this decoded url to gain access to DOM. Decoding the text is easy, but using the decoded url to gain access to DOM is where the problem lies.